# dyplr + dataset + percentiles

Tags: r, dplyr, percentile

I'm working with a large dataset (918 rows x 17 columns) with the intention to find the 90th percentile for each of the 15 variables, grouped by month. I can get it to run successfully, using the code below, but it is not creating a table with all of the variables. Instead it produces a table for 3 of the variables. Is there a way to expand the outcome table so it displays all of the variables?

```
Data_for_R %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(percent90_KP = quantile(KP, probs = .9),
            percent90_NE = quantile(NE, probs = .9),
            percent90_CH = quantile(CH, probs = .9),
            percent90_WE = quantile(WE, probs = .9),
            percent90_RR = quantile(RR, probs = .9),
            percent90_41 = quantile(41, probs = .9),
            percent90_PR = quantile(PR, probs = .9),
            percent90_31 = quantile(31, probs = .9),
            percent90_MC = quantile(MC, probs = .9),
            percent90_JH = quantile(JH, probs = .9),
            percent90_TD = quantile(TD, probs = .9),
            percent90_BO = quantile(BO, probs = .9),
            percent90_11 = quantile(11, probs = .9),
            percent90_42 = quantile(42, probs = .9),
            percent90_20 = quantile(20, probs = .9))
```

Which produces the following:

```
A tibble: 5 x 16
  Month     percent90_KP percent90_NE percent90_CH
  <chr>               <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 August               19.4           19.3           19.3
2 July                 18.6           17.8           17.7
3 June                 15.3           15.0           15.0
4 October              17.3           18.6           18.5
5 September            20.1           20.0           19.7
# ... with 12 more variables: percent90_WE <dbl>,
# percent90_RR <dbl>, percent90_41 <dbl>,
# percent90_PR <dbl>, percent90_31 <dbl>,
# percent90_MC <dbl>, percent90_JH <dbl>,
# percent90_TD <dbl>, percent90_BO <dbl>,
# percent90_11 <dbl>, percent90_42 <dbl>,
# percent90_20 <dbl>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm pretty new to R and coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how the output is displayed in the console. You can resize your console window to increase/decrease the number of columns are displayed.

Another option is to save the output in a variable and convert it to dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- Data_for_R %>% group_by(Month) ....
data.frame(result)
```

Moreover, you can also use `across` to avoid repeating the same quantile command for all the columns.

```
result <- Data_for_R %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(across(KP:`20`, quantile, probs = .9, .names = 'percent90_{col}'))
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you! That makes it so much easier